# Atom and Pycharm do not see python libraries

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm, atom-editor

[Atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifwrs.png)

Everything works if run from the terminal

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um91L.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In other words, include the minimal code, error, and data that allow to reproduce the problem and find it using a search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On PyCharm check if you have an active Interpreter:
File> Settings> Project: "Project Name"> Python Interpreter

If your Python Interpreter is  than choose one. Your best choice would be the one: /usr/bin/python3.x

On Atom you have to create your Virtual Environment. For this:

```
$ python -m venv ./venv
$ cd venv/Scripts
$ venv\Scripts> activate
```

You can check if it worked by typing:
`$ where Python`

You should see you working directory.